# Cast object from an interface to its implementation

Tags: c#, .net, interface, casting

I have the following code:

```
public interface BaseInterface
{
    int ID { get; }
}

public interface SpecialInterface1 : BaseInterface
{
    int price { get; }
}

public interface SpecialInterface1 : BaseInterface
{
    int xyz { get; }
}

public class Implementation1 : SpecialInterface
{
    int price { get; }
    int ID { get; internal set; }
}

public class Implementation2 : SpecialInterface
{
    int xyz { get; }
    int ID { get; internal set; }
}
```

Now in a Management class I want to add the objects that implement `BaseInterface` into a List.

I know that I can use `as` or `is` to cast the interface to an implementation, but in my project, I have about 10 special interfaces with an implementation each so I would have to write a really big if statements.

```
public void Add(BaseInterface u, int id)
{
    if (u is Implementation1)
    {
        ((Implementation1)u).ID = id;
        Units.Add(u);
    }

    if (u is Implementation2)
    {
        ((Implementation2)u).ID = id;
        Units.Add(u);
    }
}
```

My goal is that the id is not changeable outside the implementation and I would provide only the interfaces outside my dll so none can change the id.

Comment: You can cast to BaseInterface in all cases since it declares ID. no need for any if.

Comment: @sam But you need a cast to turn an instance of the interface into the specific implementation, which is what is being done here.

Comment: @Servy yeah, but you don't need to do that.

Comment: @sam Yes, they do, in the code shown.

Comment: @Deel96 Do you only need to access ID property in the Add method?

Comment: @Servy The code shows OP only need to access ID, which is provided by BaseInterface, so based on what i see above he does not need neither casts nor ifs.

Comment: @sam `BaseInterface` only provides a getter, not a setter.

Comment: @sam They need to _set_ the ID, via the `internal set` on the implementation itself, which the publically exposed base interface does not have.

Comment: @Servy JamesThorpe Got it.

Comment: *This is just stabbing in the dark* since I don't know how the whole thing is supposed to work, but what if you made this Management class responsible for creating instances of your implementations, keeping the actual implementations internal to your library and only exposing the interfaces, thereby disallowing direct creation of them? Who decides which id gets passed to Add? What does the id mean? If it's under your control, you could move setting the id to where the Management class creates and returns new objects, and assign it from there. It'd become a sort of Factory, broadly speaking.

Comment: You could create a BaseImplementation class which implements the BaseInterface and also adds the internal setter for the ID property, and make every further implementation inherit from BaseImplementation as well, then you could just cast the Implementation to your BaseImplementation and set the ID in your Management class

Comment: Yeah, @Spongebrot has the right solution. +1

Comment: @Deel96 Did one of the answers solve your problem.

Comment: @lqon the use of dynamic seemed to work on my project. the problem with a base class is that a inherited class would implement the special interface (and the base interface) and the baseclass would implement the base interface. So i would have 2 times an implementation of the base interface?

Comment: @Deel96 - I'm just guessing, but I bet your're over complicating your problem. Assuming these objects are generated based on a dataset from sql or other source, whatever service you are using get that data should be internal and thus able to set the ID before sending it out to the consumer no?

Answer (score 4):

A solution would be to add an extra interface. This eliminates the internal setter in your implementation.

```
internal interface IChangeID
{
    void SetID(int id);
}

public interface IBaseInterface
{
    int ID { get; }
}

public class Implementation : IBaseInterface,
                              IChangeID
{        
    public void SetID(int id) { ID = id; }
    public int ID { get; private set; }
}
```

Only the real implementations should implement `IChangeID`. Returning `IBaseInterface` or `ISpecialInterface` will hide the setter, because those interfaces do not inherit from `IChangeID`.

This would change your add into:

```
public void Add(BaseInterface u, int id)
{
     ((IChangeID)u).SetID(id);
     Units.Add(u);
}
```

If you do want to return the concrete types, not interfaces. You could implement the given interface explicit. This will hide the set method even from the concrete implementation.

```
public class Implementation : IBaseInterface,
                              IChangeID
{        
    void IChangeID.SetID(int id) { ID = id; }
    public int ID { get; private set; }
}

var obj = new Implementation();
obj.SetID() // This WILL NOT Compile
```

Comment: What? How are you able to use `internal` on an interface? That can't even compile.

Comment: see https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/interfaces.md#interface-declarations and https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/namespaces.md#type-declarations - internal should be perfectly fine and, I tested it before posting, will compile.

Comment: See what? `internal set` won't compile in an interface property

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what those links are supposed to mean. Declaring something as `internal` on an interface does not even begin to make sense, if you think about it.

Comment: The *links* are about *interface* or *type* modifiers. Not property setters. You can have an internal type or interface, but not an internal set

Comment: Oh, sry my fault. I thought about `internal interface` which is valid. But an internal member is not. Will edit the post. Thank you

Comment: If you could add public SetID function, you would be able also add public set accessor to property. This is what not want OP.

Comment: No, it is a different method for hiding the setter. Because the library consumer doesn't know the interface ```IChangeID```, he won't be able to call ```SetID```.

Comment: I like this answer the best, but I recommend making the ID a required parameter of all the implementation's constructors. This is because any instance of this object without this ID set is invalid and can cause issues if it doesn't get set in some edge case. Better to throw a constructor exception early on.

Comment: @Brian Pickens as a constructor parameter? This would not solve history problem. But I agree, a mutable ID is usually a bad idea

Comment: @Iqon I don't understand your comment about the history problem.

Comment: @BrianPickens *his problem*. Sorry posted this answer from my phone - autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

If you *don't* want to modify the interfaces and implementations, you could use C# 7's pattern matching to access the implementation type without casting. It requires 3 lines per implementation type but avoids modifying the classes:

```
public void Add(BaseInterface u, int id)
{
    switch(u)
    {
        case Implementation1 u1:
            u1.ID = id;
            break;
        case Implementation2 u1:
            u1.ID = id;
            break;    
        default :
            throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected implementation!");
    }
    Units.Add(u);     
}
```

The obvious disadvantage is that the code will have to be modified if a new implementation is added.

Another option is to use `dynamic`, losing type safety. This will fail at runtime if some implementation doesn't have a setter (eg because it was replaced by constructor initialization)

```
public void Add(BaseInterface u, int id)
{
    dynamic x =u;
    x.ID=id;
    Units.Add(x);     
}
```

Comment: C#7 "pattern matching" (air quotes) is the only reasonable solution.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic depends on the requirements. A "writer" inteface is safer

Comment: All Implementations would have a internal setable ID. The use of dynamic seemed to work on my project but im not 100% sure if i should use it.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Any reason in particular or just feeling grumpy ?

Answer (score 1):

While I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46079289/1186161) the best,

I recommend making the ID a required parameter of all the implementation's constructors, and then to use a factory pattern to generate any instance you require. This makes any instance without the ID set throw an exception at compile time rather than runtime reducing the probability of exceptions.

Here is a simple example that gets you what you want without an additional interface. Should you choose you can combine my answer with @Iqon's answer.

```
public interface IInterface
{
    int ID { get; }
}

internal class InternalImplementation: IInterface {
    public InternalImplementation(int ID) { this.ID = ID; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class MyImplementationFactoryService {

    public IInterface Create() {
        int id = 1 // Or however you get your ID, possibly from a DB query?
        return new InternalImplementation(id);
    }

    public IInterface Create(type|enum createtype) {
        // return type based on typeof or enum
    }

}
```

Comment: This would prevent that the consumer of your library can create the objects. But if I understand correctly, your library will manage those object, which means your library should also be the creator.

Comment: Yes and no. The consumer would not be able to new up any internal implementations, but a simple factory method would take care of that issue. However there is nothing to prevent the consumer from attempting to use its own implementations either.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use reflection to set property, code below may help

```
public interface IBaseInterface
{
   int ID { get; }
}

public class Impl1 : IBaseInterface 
{
    public int ID { get; internal set; }

    public int Price {get; set;}
}

public class Impl2 : IBaseInterface 
{
    public int ID { get { return 0;} }

    public int Subscription {get; set;}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IBaseInterface obj1 = new Impl1();

        SetProperty(obj1, "ID", 100);
        Console.WriteLine("Object1 Id is {0}", obj1.ID); 

        IBaseInterface obj2 = new Impl2();

        SetProperty(obj2, "ID", 500);
        Console.WriteLine("Object2 Id is {0}", obj2.ID); 
    }

    private static void SetProperty(IBaseInterface obj, string propertyName, object id){
        if(obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).CanWrite) {
            obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(obj, id); 
            Console.WriteLine("CanWrite property '{0}' : {1}" , propertyName, obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).CanWrite); 
        }
    }
}
```

Output

CanWrite property 'ID' : True

Object1 Id is 100

Object2 Id is 0

Comment: I would not recommend this solution because the whole idea was to keep the consumer from being able to set the ID.

Comment: @BrianPickens not sure if I understood ur comment however this code will not allow consumer to set value. Intention behind this code is to use reflection instead of type checking to set value. Everything remains same as other solutions above, except for using type casting to Class with writable ID use reflection SetValue.